# How to create a folder and write a simple .txt file in that folder on Internal Storage on Android

Tags: java, android

I cant seem to get the following code to work; i've tried diffrent methods but none work, i wanna create a folder int he internal storage and a create and write to a simple .txt file within that folder. Can someone please provide a robust example of how to do it, and show me what i'm getting wrong

```
 String DataIn = PhoneNumber + "," + dataLong + "," + dataLat;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        String filename = "LegionData";
        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(DataIn.getBytes());
               outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Files created in this location will not be easy to verify other than with the app itself, so your program is as likely to be with how you are determining success/failure as with the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  String filename = "myfile";
  File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

Comment: This is incomplete and does not do anything.  If it were complete, it would do about the same thing as the posted code.

Comment: Check out the "Using the Internal Storage" section at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.

Comment: yes i know its incomplete, i meant that after i implement the changes he was implying the code didnt work